# How to replace occurrences in string with array values in javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, replace, indexof

I have the following string and array:

```
var message = 'This is a @[20] very fun, @[75] evening.';
var array_values = {"20": "really", "112": "extreme", "75": "happy"};
```

How do I replace the @[number] occurrences with the corresponding array values, to get this:

```
message = 'This is a really very fun, happy evening.';
```

Thanks!

Comment: `array_values` is not an array....

Comment: Yeah - `array_values` is an object. If you want an array, run `Object.keys(array_values)` to get an array containing the keys of that object.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
var parsed = message.replace(/@\[(\d+)\]/g, function(m, v) {
    return array_values[v] || m;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```js
var message = 'This is a @[20] very fun, @[75] evening.';
var array_values = {"20": "really", "112": "extreme", "75": "happy"};

for( var key in array_values ) {
  if( array_values.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
    message = message.replace( '@[' + key + ']', array_values[ key ] );
  }
}

console.log( message );
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible way

```
for (var key in array_values) {
   message = message.replace('@[' + key + ']', array_values[key]);
}
```